# Neo4jClient - Returning labels belonging to node

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

In using the Neo4j client for .NET I have not been able to find a way to capture labels belonging to a specific node.

I can observe that this data is available by capturing network traffic, but I cannot find any way to retrieve this data using the API. The same applies to retrieving the node IDs - I can observe those on the wire, but not in code.

Is this not yet implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be dealing with node ids. They are deprecated, and will go away more and more.

To retrieve the labels, copying straight from https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples, this Cypher:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE user.Id = 1234
RETURN labels(user)
```

Is this C#:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == 1234)
    .Return(user => user.Labels())
    .Results
```

Comment: In the network request for a query, if I return the node directly, it comes back with a metadata property with the nodeId (I know you said that is deprecated now), but also the "labels" array. It looks like that labels property is not getting deserialized into Node<T>, as well as the other relationship properties with URIs, is there a reason those properties aren't being deserialized into C# properties on Node<T>?